# iphone sdk 4.3 running unit test from command line

Tags: command-line, xcode4, iphone, unit-testing

i like to run test cases from the command line but there is a little problem… maybe someone can help me…

i' ve created a simple HelloWorld Project with XCode4! The build works fine.

xcodebuild -project HelloWorld.xcodeproj -target HelloWorld -sdk iphonesimulator4.3 -configuration "Debug"

But the test doesn't work (i use the default unit test which xcode4 creates)

xcodebuild -project HelloWorld.xcodeproj -target HelloWorldTests -sdk iphonesimulator4.3 -configuration "Debug"

Here are some interesting outputs:

> === BUILD NATIVE TARGET HelloWorld OF PROJECT HelloWorld WITH THE
>   DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===
>   Check dependencies

And

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Tools/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests:95:
>   warning: Skipping tests; the
>   iPhoneSimulator platform does not
>   currently support application-hosted
>   tests (TEST_HOST set).

I guess the last output is the problem but i haven't any idea to fix it :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though you may have unit tests and application tests mixed up. Referring to the two following sources (especially the non-apple one) will help you out a lot:

[Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html)

[CocoaWithLove Article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/12/sample-iphone-application-with-complete.html)

Comment: You're right. I switched to GHUnit to implement my unit test cases.